# IOS In App Purchasing Unavailable Product

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I've been trying to get Unity IAP working with IOS through TestFlight for a while now to no avail.
Here are my errors and what I suspect may be the case.  I submitted my app to Apple, and I had some selection wrong so they rejected it.  Now my IAPs are in this "Developer Action Needed" state.  There doesn't appear to be anything I can do to get them out of it.

[App Store Connect IAP Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Rrs.png)

This could be the issue, but I read in a couple places that TestFlight doesn't need "Approved" IAP products in order for them to work, but maybe "Developer Action Needed" is different.  I'm not even sure why the IAPs are in this state.  They're all complete.  I think apple won't mark them "Approved" until they approve your app as well?  I submitted some IAP products seperately from the Features tab and they are also now "Developer Action Needed."  Can anyone shed some light?

I ran the game through my IPhone debugging to Xcode, and I got this error for every product:

```
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Unavailable product com.BlueFlamingoGames.Aeroplane._10_tickets -com.BlueFlamingoGames.Aeroplane._10_tickets
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
```

Maybe this is explained by "Developer Action Needed," or this is why my IAPs are labeled "Developer Action Needed?"  I really have no clue.

I did manage to get this all working for Google Play.  It's the exact same code, aside from initializing Play Store instead of App Store, and the difference in Store IDs.  So, I believe the code is fine.  Anyways, I'll attach it below if that could be useful.  This is all I've got to go off of, so any ideas are welcome.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Purchaser : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener
{

    public static Purchaser Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);
        else
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private static IStoreController m_StoreController;          // The Unity Purchasing system.
    private static IExtensionProvider m_StoreExtensionProvider; // The store-specific Purchasing subsystems.

    // Product identifiers for all products capable of being purchased: 
    // "convenience" general identifiers for use with Purchasing, and their store-specific identifier 
    // counterparts for use with and outside of Unity Purchasing. Define store-specific identifiers 
    // also on each platform's publisher dashboard (iTunes Connect, Google Play Developer Console, etc.)

    // General product identifiers for the consumable, non-consumable, and subscription products.
    // Use these handles in the code to reference which product to purchase. Also use these values 
    // when defining the Product Identifiers on the store. Except, for illustration purposes, the 
    // kProductIDSubscription - it has custom Apple and Google identifiers. We declare their store-
    // specific mapping to Unity Purchasing's AddProduct, below.
    public static string _3_tickets = "com.BlueFlamingoGames.Aeroplane._3_tickets";
    public static string _5_tickets = "com.BlueFlamingoGames.Aeroplane._6_tickets";
    public static string _10_tickets = "com.BlueFlamingoGames.Aeroplane._10_tickets";
    public static string remove_ads = "com.BlueFlamingoGames.Aeroplane.removeAds";

    public static string kProductIDNonConsumable = "nonconsumable";
    public static string kProductIDConsumable = "consumable";
    public static string kProductIDSubscription = "subscription";

    // Apple App Store-specific product identifier for the subscription product.
    private static string kProductNameAppleSubscription = "com.unity3d.subscription.new";

    // Google Play Store-specific product identifier subscription product.
    private static string kProductNameGooglePlaySubscription = "com.unity3d.subscription.original";

    void Start()
    {
        // If we haven't set up the Unity Purchasing reference
        if (m_StoreController == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("SETUP");
            // Begin to configure our connection to Purchasing
            InitializePurchasing();
        }
    }

    public void InitializePurchasing()
    {
        // If we have already connected to Purchasing ...
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            // ... we are done here.
            return;
        }

        // Create a builder, first passing in a suite of Unity provided stores.
        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
        Debug.Log("Initialize");
        builder.AddProduct(_3_tickets, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){
                { _3_tickets, AppleAppStore.Name },
                { _3_tickets, GooglePlay.Name },
            });
        builder.AddProduct(_5_tickets, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){
                { _5_tickets, AppleAppStore.Name },
                { _5_tickets, GooglePlay.Name },
            });
        builder.AddProduct(_10_tickets, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){
                { _10_tickets, AppleAppStore.Name },
                { _10_tickets, GooglePlay.Name },
            });
        builder.AddProduct(remove_ads, ProductType.NonConsumable, new IDs(){
                { remove_ads, AppleAppStore.Name },
                { remove_ads, GooglePlay.Name },
            });

        foreach (string ID in SaveLoadManager.planeIDs)
        {
            string id = "com.BlueFlamingoGames.Aeroplane." + ID;
            builder.AddProduct(id, ProductType.NonConsumable, new IDs(){
                { id, AppleAppStore.Name },
                { id, GooglePlay.Name },
            });
        }
        foreach (string ID in SaveLoadManager.characterIDs)
        {
            string id = "com.BlueFlamingoGames.Aeroplane." + ID;
            builder.AddProduct(id, ProductType.NonConsumable, new IDs(){
                { id, AppleAppStore.Name },
                { id, GooglePlay.Name },
            });
        }
        //builder.AddProduct(DHC2Beaver, ProductType.Consumable);
        // Add a product to sell / restore by way of its identifier, associating the general identifier
        // with its store-specific identifiers.
        // Continue adding the non-consumable product.
        builder.AddProduct(kProductIDNonConsumable, ProductType.NonConsumable);
        // And finish adding the subscription product. Notice this uses store-specific IDs, illustrating
        // if the Product ID was configured differently between Apple and Google stores. Also note that
        // one uses the general kProductIDSubscription handle inside the game - the store-specific IDs 
        // must only be referenced here. 
        builder.AddProduct(kProductIDSubscription, ProductType.Subscription, new IDs(){
                { kProductNameAppleSubscription, AppleAppStore.Name },
                { kProductNameGooglePlaySubscription, GooglePlay.Name },
            });

        // Kick off the remainder of the set-up with an asynchrounous call, passing the configuration 
        // and this class' instance. Expect a response either in OnInitialized or OnInitializeFailed.
        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }


    private bool IsInitialized()
    {
        // Only say we are initialized if both the Purchasing references are set.
        return m_StoreController != null && m_StoreExtensionProvider != null;
    }


    public void BuyConsumable(string productID)
    {
        // Buy the consumable product using its general identifier. Expect a response either 
        // through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
        BuyProductID(productID);
    }


    public void BuyNonConsumable(string productID)
    {
        // Buy the non-consumable product using its general identifier. Expect a response either 
        // through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
        BuyProductID(productID);
    }


    public void BuySubscription()
    {
        // Buy the subscription product using its the general identifier. Expect a response either 
        // through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
        // Notice how we use the general product identifier in spite of this ID being mapped to
        // custom store-specific identifiers above.
        BuyProductID(kProductIDSubscription);
    }


    void BuyProductID(string productId)
    {
        // If Purchasing has been initialized ...
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            // ... look up the Product reference with the general product identifier and the Purchasing 
            // system's products collection.
            Product product = m_StoreController.products.WithID(productId);

            // If the look up found a product for this device's store and that product is ready to be sold ... 
            if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("Purchasing product asychronously: '{0}'", product.definition.id));
                // ... buy the product. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed 
                // asynchronously.
                m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);
            }
            // Otherwise ...
            else
            {
                // ... report the product look-up failure situation  
                Debug.Log("BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase");
            }
        }
        // Otherwise ...
        else
        {
            // ... report the fact Purchasing has not succeeded initializing yet. Consider waiting longer or 
            // retrying initiailization.
            Debug.Log("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
        }
    }


    // Restore purchases previously made by this customer. Some platforms automatically restore purchases, like Google. 
    // Apple currently requires explicit purchase restoration for IAP, conditionally displaying a password prompt.
    public void RestorePurchases()
    {
        // If Purchasing has not yet been set up ...
        if (!IsInitialized())
        {
            // ... report the situation and stop restoring. Consider either waiting longer, or retrying initialization.
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not initialized.");
            return;
        }

        // If we are running on an Apple device ... 
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer)
        {
            // ... begin restoring purchases
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases started ...");

            // Fetch the Apple store-specific subsystem.
            var apple = m_StoreExtensionProvider.GetExtension<IAppleExtensions>();
            // Begin the asynchronous process of restoring purchases. Expect a confirmation response in 
            // the Action<bool> below, and ProcessPurchase if there are previously purchased products to restore.
            apple.RestoreTransactions((result) => {
                // The first phase of restoration. If no more responses are received on ProcessPurchase then 
                // no purchases are available to be restored.
                Debug.Log("RestorePurchases continuing: " + result + ". If no further messages, no purchases available to restore.");
            });
        }
        // Otherwise ...
        else
        {
            // We are not running on an Apple device. No work is necessary to restore purchases.
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not supported on this platform. Current = " + Application.platform);
        }
    }


    //  
    // --- IStoreListener
    //

    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        // Purchasing has succeeded initializing. Collect our Purchasing references.
        Debug.Log("OnInitialized: PASS");

        // Overall Purchasing system, configured with products for this application.
        m_StoreController = controller;
        // Store specific subsystem, for accessing device-specific store features.
        m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;
    }


    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        // Purchasing set-up has not succeeded. Check error for reason. Consider sharing this reason with the user.
        Debug.Log("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error);
    }


    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args)
    {
        // A consumable product has been purchased by this user.
        foreach(string ID in SaveLoadManager.planeIDs)
        {
            String app_id = "com.BlueFlamingoGames.Aeroplane." + ID;
            if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, app_id, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
                SaveLoadPlayerData.Instance.earn_characterOrPlane(ID);
                return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
            }
        }
        foreach (string ID in SaveLoadManager.characterIDs)
        {
            String app_id = "com.BlueFlamingoGames.Aeroplane." + ID;
            if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, app_id, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
                SaveLoadPlayerData.Instance.earn_characterOrPlane(ID);
                return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
            }
        }

        if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, _3_tickets, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
            int tickets = SaveLoadPlayerData.Instance.get_tickets();
            SaveLoadPlayerData.Instance.set_tickets(tickets + 3);
            return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
        }

        if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, _5_tickets, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
            int tickets = SaveLoadPlayerData.Instance.get_tickets();
            SaveLoadPlayerData.Instance.set_tickets(tickets + 6);
            return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
        }

        if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, _10_tickets, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
            int tickets = SaveLoadPlayerData.Instance.get_tickets();
            SaveLoadPlayerData.Instance.set_tickets(tickets + 10);
            return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
        }

        if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, remove_ads, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
            SaveLoadPlayerData.Instance.remove_ads();
            return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't fill out some banking criteria.  Make sure all necessary information is filled.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30342407)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you
When I click to buy, the pop-up window shows service unavailable
The log output from my device is exactly the same as yours
My code can be used normally on googleplay
I guess the reason for my problem is because I am in China, and the product I developed is global
I am still trying to find out why
Hope to get a solution